# Unity, In Android onClick.AddListener is not working, but in editor its working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Yesterday its working well but today when i open the unity and taken build, onClick.AddListener is not working in Android, but it working in Unity Editor.

```
void Start(){
    instance = this;
guestBtn.onClick.AddListener (GuestBtnFun);
         }
public void GuestBtnFun()
        {
            guestBackBtn.SetActive (true);
            pic.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            nameText.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            shareBtn.gameObject.SetActive (true);

            if (!GameSaver.instance.isTutorialShow)
                tutorialPanel.SetActive (true);
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you have EventSystem added to your scene.

Comment: Ya it has added . That what in editor it's working but not in Android.

Comment: Have you tried running adb logcat to see if there are any errors?